# How to create a bar chart of means in Stata?

Tags: stata

I am trying to create a bar chart of mean scores on a survey (variable name is scale_climate) by treatment group. I have tried the following code:

```
hist scale_climate, by(treatment, col(1)) fcolor(gs11) lcolor(gs5) scheme(s1color) xsize(4) ysize(5) title("Climate Scale by Treatment") name(hist_scale_climate, replace)
```

But this code is creating four graphs with density plots, as shown in the image attached here.

How can I change this code to create one graph of mean climate_score (continuous variable) by treatment (categorical)?[image]

Comment: How would that be different from what you have?

Comment: Essentially, I want to have one graph with four bars. Each bar shows the mean climate_scale score by treatment. So there would be four bars, one for Treatment 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: The condition `if exclude == 0` may be important to you, but it is not explained and as such is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, just edited my post.

Comment: Without rewriting this question is unlikely to be useful to others, as it is confused on an elementary statistical point.

Comment: I took the liberty of rewriting it further. You're at liberty to roll back the edits. The question still hinges on a statistical misunderstanding.

Comment: No I appreciate the edits, hopefully it will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

This code works:

```
graph bar (mean) scale_climate, over(treatment) blabel(bar) ytitle(Climate Scale) title(Climate Scale by Treatment)
```

Comment: That's a bar chart of means, naturally. It's not a histogram as understood in statistics.